# Mongoose returns null for parameters that should have values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose model that is returning null values for some parameters when I know the value is not null in the database.
I have a schema that is defined as such:

```
  module.exports = function (mongoose) {
  const Types = mongoose.Schema.Types;
  const collectionName = "audit_todays_date"
  const Schema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
      employeeName: {
        type: Types.String,
      },
      adminGroup: {
        type: Types.String,
      },
      days: {
        type: Types.String,
      },
      lanId: {
        type: Types.String,
      },
      bedDev: {
        type: Types.String,
      },
      followUp: {
        type: Types.String,
      },
      totalVariance: {
        type: Types.Number,
      },
      highRisk: {
        type: Types.Number,
      },
      highModRisk: {
        type: Types.Number,
      },
      modRisk: {
        type: Types.Number,
      },
      lowRisk: {
        type: Types.Number,
      },
      busPractveEventsRisk: {
        type: Types.Number,
      },
      otherRisk: {
        type: Types.Number,
      },
      batch_id: {
        type: Types.Number,
      },
      createdAt: {
        type: Types.Date,
      },
      serviceGroup: {
        type: Types.String,
      },
      riskScoreFlag: {
        type: Types.String,
      },
      riskTotalPercentage:{
        type: Types.Number
      },
      facility: {
        type: Types.String,
      },
      campus: {
        type: Types.String,
      },
      region: {
        type: Types.String,
      },
    },
    {
      collection: "audit_todays_date",
    }
  );
  Schema.index({ 'lanID': 1 })
    Schema.index({ 'adminGroup': 1 })
    Schema.index({ 'employeeName': 1 })
    Schema.index({ 'bedDev': 1 })
    Schema.index({ 'maxStdDeviation': 1 })
      
  Schema.statics = {
    collectionName: collectionName,
    routeOptions: {
      allowList: false,
      allowRead: false,
      allowCreate: false,
      allowUpdate: false,
      allowDelete: false,
    },
  };
  return Schema;
};
```

I am running an aggregation query this:

```
model = mongoose.model('audit_todays_date')
aggPipe = [{$match{flag_priority:{$gte:8}}},
        {$group:{
            "_id":{"regionId":"$regionId"},
            "groupCount":{$sum:1},
            "group":{$first:"$region"}
        }}
var data = await model.aggregate(aggPipe).allowDiskUse(true)
```

I am getting the correct group counts as expect but, I am getting null for "group" every time. I have the region defined in the model and I know that there is a value for region in the database.
This is what mongoose returns:

```
  { _id: { regionId: 'swwi' }, groupCount: 8, group: null },
  { _id: { regionId: 'florida' }, groupCount: 23, group: null },
  { _id: { regionId: 'arizona' }, groupCount: 21, group: null },
  { _id: { regionId: 'rochester' }, groupCount: 84, group: null },
  { _id: { regionId: 'semn' }, groupCount: 7, group: null },
  { _id: { regionId: 'swmn' }, groupCount: 11, group: null },
  { _id: { regionId: 'nwwi' }, groupCount: 16, group: null }
```

This is what is returned when ran in Sudito3t
[image]

I can't tell if I assigned something incorrect in my schema or if I am not calling the model correctly?? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The answer would require debugging. All looks good at a glance, but there no regionId in the schema for example. I would start from enabling the profiler on mongodb with level 2 to record all queries, then run the mongoose aggregation, and evaluated what query it generates in the logs, compared with the query that yields expected results, etc.

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks for the suggestion. Turns out, its querying from an entirely different collection that has similar data but not ALL the same parameters. Of course my question now is why that might happen but at least I can fudge it for now.

Comment: `flag_priority` isn't in your schema but doing a `$match` on it. First red flag. Setting a `group` property on the `$group` stage using the `$region` property resulting in `null` is the second red flag it's a different db/collection. As an aside, you should pass the schema as the second parameter to the `mongoose.model` method e.g. `mongoose.model('audit_todays_date', schemaHere)`. Glad you identified the problem.